# Create a regex which accept all the js and css file except config.js

Tags: javascript, regex

In my folder I've got several files (js, css, json, md etc...) and I want to target all the js and css files except the config.js. My regex works separately but I've got difficulties to have the full one

Regex which not accept config.js :

```js
/^(?!.*config).*$/
```

Regex which accept all js and css files :

```js
/\.(js|css)$/
```

And I tried with :

```js
/^(?!.*config)(?=\.(js|css)).*$/
```

But no success ! I don't find my mistake

Any idea ?

Comment: `/^(?!config\.js$).*\.(?:js|css)$/` or `/^(?!(?:.*\/)?config\.js$).*\.(?:js|css)$/`

Comment: Both doesn't work, I've tried on regex101.com with hello.js and config.js

Comment: [They work](https://regex101.com/r/93Wtfo/2) [well](https://regex101.com/r/93Wtfo/1)

Comment: Does it _have to be_ a regular expression? If _not_, maybe you can just `.filter` the list of files/filenames to exclude any file that has `config` in it's name. Please add a bit of context in which setup you are working and how you get a handle on the files.

Comment: Yes you're right Wiktor, it works thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
/^(?!config\.js$).*\.(?:js|css)$/
```

Or, if `config.js` can be preceded with some path,

```js
/^(?!(?:.*\/)?config\.js$).*\.(?:js|css)$/
```

See the regex [demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/93Wtfo/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/93Wtfo/2)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:.*\/)?config\.js$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are

  - `(?:.*\/)?` - an optional sequence of any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and then `/`
  - `config\.js`  - a `config.js` string
  - `$` - end of string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `(?:js|css)` - `js` or `css`
- `$` - end of string.